# Passing Parameters Among Functions During Matlab Optimization

Tags: matlab

I am trying to optimise about 10 parameters using genetic algorithm. I need to pass intermediate values of the parameters within the main function to another function, which is basically ODE solver for a system of linear ODEs, with the parameters as coefficients in the differential equation. I will then return the solution to the ODE back into the main function I am trying to minimize. I have tried declaring the variables as global, but it doesn't seem to help. Please advise on how best to pass the variable between the 2 functions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but I think it should work. You could try wrapping them in a handle class, and then just pass that as an object.

### yourClass.m

```
classdef yourClass < handle
  properties
    v1;
    v2;
  end
end
```

Then in whatever function you call... (could even make it method of your class)

### yourFunction.m

```
function yourFunction( p1 )
 p1.v1 = 21;
 p1.v2 = 22;
end
```

So, you could use it like this...

```
>> o = yourClass();
>> o.v1 = 1;
>> o.v2 = 2;
>> o
o = 

yourClass handle

Properties:
  v1: 1
  v2: 2

Methods, Events, Superclasses

>> yourFunction(o);
>> o
o = 

yourClass handle

Properties:
  v1: 21
  v2: 22

Methods, Events, Superclasses
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easier and more "standard" ...

### yourFunction.m

```
function [v1 v2] = yourFunction(v1,v2)
  v1 = 13;
  v2 = 22;
end
```

And here is how you use it...

### using yourFunction

```
>> v1 = 1;
>> v2 = 2;
>> [v1 v2] = yourFunction(v1,v2);
>> v1
>>  13
>> v2
>>  22
```